# How to persist cookies using Apache HttpClient after authenticating against Java app with form-based spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, cookies

I have a Java app (jetty server) built with Spring (MVC, security, transactions, etc) and uses REST for webservices. I have another Java client that makes REST calls to the server using Apache HTTPClient (HttpComponents). The server app uses form-based authentication and web client uses j_spring_security_check form to login to the app. So, from Java client I use [https://host:port/myapp/j_spring_security_check?j_username=myuser&j_password=mypass] using POST to do the login. Authentication is working fine (it reaches the UserDetailService's child class and successfully does authentication), but subsequent REST calls fail indicating as if user was not authenticated (the call doesn't even reach the controller method for the given rest call). I get back one of the app's html page (this is one of the jsp pages).

I am printing Cookies for every request (including login) and it prints different jsessionid for each request (request is the rest call to the server). Here are the cookies, one for each request, first request is the login request (see that jsessionid is different for each request):

```
cookies: [[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 1x5i3b0lbf5o7xv52kjh0vu89][domain: 127.0.0.1][path: /webui][expiry: null]]
cookies: [[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: t05vbrffqv6t1xcygps9l6jaz][domain: 127.0.0.1][path: /webui][expiry: null]]
cookies: [[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 8v5i5ofbgr201kh2txxale674][domain: 127.0.0.1][path: /webui][expiry: null]]
```

is different jsessionid for each request the problem/cause? How do I get around this problem? Here is the code with HttpClient:

```
    request = new HttpPost(url);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();        

    httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory));

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    System.out.println("cookies: " + httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies());
    HttpEntity resp_ent = response.getEntity();
    this.status_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Do we need to do anything special to store the cookies? Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious from the code snippet you showed, so I'm not sure if this is the problem, but make sure you don't create a `new DefaultHttpClient()` for each request, otherwise the new client will have a new `CookieStore`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to clarify the flow.
After a successful authentication a (Java) server adds a JSESSIONID cookie to a response. A client (a browser or other client; in our case it is Apache HTTP client) takes the cookie from the response and sends it with a new request. Then, when the request access to the server with the cookie – it can check that the request is authenticated and will not require an authentication. Otherwise (the request without a cookie) the server requires an authentication.

In your case when you use Apache HTTP client without the cookie store each request sent without the cookie. To fix it you need to allocate the cookie store. You should do it only once (in PostConstructor):

```
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Create a local instance of cookie store
        cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        // Set the store
        httpClient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
```

Then, you perform your calls using the same instance of the client. The client will take a cookie from a response, will store it in the cookieStore and will send it with the next request.

Please tell me if you need any additional clarifications.

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: Thx Michael. I didn't have to use setCokkieStore and it worked fine. I changed it to not instantiate DefaultHttpClient() for every request and it fixed it.